# Was there an effort to clean up "See Wiki" type questions?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

Was there an effort to clean up "See Wiki" basic type of questions on SciFi SE, similar to the effort to clean up "lists" questions?

As an example, this one:

[In the Dune series, why are they not using computers and programming related technologies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164/in-the-dune-series-why-are-they-not-using-computers-and-programming-related-tech)

Seems to match the FAQ's *off-topic* rule of **Facts easily found on a reference site: Who played X in Y?**

(there may be more - I stumbled on the Dune one by accident).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [mass-moderator-closing of list questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/411/culling-list-and-recommendation-questions) was done for several reasons:

- These questions were easily collected, based on tags (set by the community, not by moderators).
- List questions tend to gather more and more answers over time, so closing makes a difference.
- List questions are easy to identify unambiguously.

None of these reasons apply to too-basic questions.

Furthermore, I don't think [your example](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/164/in-the-dune-series-why-are-they-not-using-computers-and-programming-related-tech) is that basic. Sure, [Wikipedia has an answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dune_%28novel%29#Setting), but I don't find the [Butlerian Jihad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butlerian_Jihad) article completely satisfactory, for example it doesn't explain why computers didn't survive in a splinter group and eventually reappear (yes, I guess the answer is author fiat).

Comment: this is off-topic for Meta :), but I'm not 100% certain that the full Dune universe precludes your "survive in a splinter group and eventually reappear" idea. There were a lot of weird things in the larger physical Universe alluded to in the latter sequels. This might make an interesting question for SE site - I'll ask when I have time, or feel free to run with the idea and ask yourself :)

Comment: Upon a second look, I'm still somewhat convinced that the question I used as example is against the FAQ but I see where you have a valid point. I was more interested in organized effort as a conept anyway, so your answer is 100% what I was looking for, thanks!