# Why is this question put on hold?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

Some people have put [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158647/has-any-superhero-attempted-suicide-because-theyve-had-enough) on hold; it has lost its momentum and now will not be a Hot Network Question.

It has answers and is absolutely not too broad as there have not been very many superheroes who have committed suicide.
So what is the reason that people decided to put it on hold?

Comment: I did not vote to close it, but it is a bit broad in my opinion, so I also did not vote to reopen it. "Superheroes" covers a fairly broad spectrum. You didn't specify a universe. And it's only fairly recently that the question changed from asking for "all superheroes who have or have not committed suicide". :)

Comment: In my opinion, it's a list question, they are closed

Comment: What would you do if someone posted a question asking if any superheroes can fly?

Comment: I don't appreciate being called obtuse.

Comment: @Valorum, Can't say I disagree with the question.

Comment: @KyloRen - You don't think it's a list question? And too broad to answer sensibly?

Comment: @Valorum, absolutely not. How many super heroes have commited suicide like I asked? If the answer is very few few, than it is not too too broad.

Comment: Related discussion: [How should we handle “any” (list) questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/5184).

Comment: Having attempted even if not succeeded, as per your question? Valorum provided links to discussions that look to have at least a round half-dozen just within comic-books. As I commented, this could get expanded out if you include TV Series and films, even more so if you include non-powered heroes, who may not even wear costumes.

Comment: **Don't be rude about other users** (this is in reference to your calling people "obtuse" for nothing more than VTCing your question).

Comment: @Randal'Thor, that was not an insult, I generally believe those who closed the question were slow to understand what it was asking. As it stands , out of the whole superhero universe, 3 have committed suicide or tried to. How is that too broad?

Comment: @KyloRen - Because it's not three, it's dozens, probably hundreds. Even the most cursory search revealed a half-dozen in the very first link I looked at.

Comment: @Valorum, can you link to that search, I found no one.

Comment: @KyloRen - I searched for 'superhero suicides'

Comment: @Valorum, that results in very few results of what you are talking of.

Comment: @KyloRen Just because you generally (genuinely?) believe something doesn't make it not an insult. I advise you to learn better if you want to continue using this site, as [not being insulting is a rule here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Answer (score 9):

I voted to close it for a few different reasons.

- It's too generic.

As it stands, the question is asking whether there has ever been an instance where "a superhero" has killed themselves. This potentially encompasses tens of thousands of properties, maybe hundreds of thousands. Even the most cursory search revealed a half-dozen in the [very first link](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/gen-discussion-1/has-any-superhero-committed-suicide-1523908/)

- It's too vague.

You've not defined what you mean by superhero. Are you only after comic book characters or would you also include film, radio, TV?

- It's a list question.

Before it got closed you had three equally good answers, all offering one example per answer. If it gets reopened, you could end up with potentially dozens of equally good answers,  each offering a single example.

Comment: While I agree with you in principle, the [previous meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/5184) was that questions like this should remain open - by a very large margin.

Comment: @phantom42 - I think the key difference is that this question is asking something that's happened dozens of times just in Marvel comics, as opposed to something that may have only happened once or twice in all comic properties, let alone **all* properties.

Comment: Not only thousands of properties, but literally _every_ media that superheroes appear in. It's not scoped to just comics, books, TV, movies, radio, webcomics, etc. It's asking about ***all*** of those.

Comment: I agree that it's too broad, and needs to be cut down to at least a specific universe, but this is just an "any-list" question, and policy is that they're ok.

Comment: @phantom42 - "any list" questions should be reasonably scoped, otherwise I could just write a short fanfic and answer it with my own work

Comment: @phantom42 I'd agree with that, too. Too broad because of the scope, not because it's a list question.

Comment: we've established that fan-fics are on-topic, and acceptable to answer from if OP the parameters of the question allow for it. so, go for it.

Comment: Let me be clear: I greatly disagree with this policy regarding the "any/list" questions, but it *is* the current policy.

Comment: @phantom42 - No, because that would be stupid. Bad questions encourage poor answers.

Comment: Again, *I agree* - but the policy on "any" questions is that they're not the same as  "list questions", so your "list question" argument doesn't hold.