# Why was this question about Captain America closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My [question about fanfic on Captain America](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230773/is-there-any-fan-fiction-about-capn-amerca-meeting-red-skull-to-return-an-infini) was closed, but no explanation was given. It was closed as "off topic" but there are other questions about Captain America, Marvel Cinematic Universe, and fan fiction.

What would you change to make it on topic?

Comment: The problem is, how do we determine _which_ answer is the correctest?

Comment: @Moöz Green checkmark, or failing that, max votes.

Answer (score 7):

I voted to close as "recommendations", as noted in the closed banner.

Quite simply, while ["is there any" questions are *usually* considered OK(ish)](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1465/98028)*, I personally draw a line at fanfiction. Anyone can go and put one up, there are dozens if not thousands of fanfics out there, skimming through them to find a plot some user wonders about doesn't fall into what I think this site should be about (story-id questions are another matter).

Personally, I don't really see a legitimate way to make it on-topic.

---

*<sub>Though I personally abhor this policy and think it should be revised.</sub>

Comment: "Are there any" questions are the weasel-worded offspring of recommendation questions. I've no idea why we allow them.

Comment: What's the difference between this and [tag:story-identification]?

Comment: @Alex story identification relies on a number of concrete details that the original OP remembers having seen or read in the past. The  [Good Story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) contains a lot of information about how to write them. An "is there any" is a flight of fancy of the poster wondering if someone's done something without any real expectation. Admittedly some of the minimalist StoryID questions are little different from this, but those tend to get closed as well.