# Is it OK to ask a question in the form "Are there any sci-fi books featuring this plot element"?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it ok to ask a 'plot element' question? Something such as, "Are there any sci-fi books where a future Earth uses the gold standard'?

Comment: Technically speaking this is a duplicate of [How should we handle "any" (list) questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/how-should-we-handle-any-list-questions), but the votes on [How about revisiting our policy about “is there any” questions being OK?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12998/98028), from two months ago, would indicate that SFF's users want a change. So... I'm not that sure where we are now, and have retracted my duplicate-close vote.

Comment: Any is essentially a list and per the above comment it might end up closed. Asking for the first occurrence where this happened with the [[tag:history-of]] tag though would be perfectly fine.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/how-about-revisiting-our-policy-about-is-there-any-questions-being-ok. I'd dupehammer it closed myself if circumstances were different.

Comment: Interestingly I wasn’t shooting for’any’ as in ‘list’ but as in ‘not zero’. Is there a good way to write that?

Comment: @VaughnOhlman - No. You're looking for a list. We don't allow those even if it turns out to be a list of one.

Comment: @Valorum, so what you're saying is it is what I'm looking for that is the problem, not the way I posed my question?

Comment: @VaughnOhlman - Open list questions are problematic because there's no definitive "right" answer. If I post a couple of examples of a trope and another user posts another couple of examples, which answer is the better one?

Comment: @Valorum, that's where I saw my rewording working. If I asked, "Is the list of sci-fi stories involving a future Earth where the economic system includes the gold standard a non-zero list?" Then there are two answers:

No. Which would have to be silence, meaning no one can think of any or

Yes. Here are a couple of examples to prove that they exist.

Neither of those are lists, let alone lists that need to be competed with.

A similar way of putting it might be, "Is it true that someone has done X before?"
Yes: One or two examples
No: silence

Comment: @VaughnOhlman -You're still trying to weasel-word yourself out of the restriction on asking list questions.

Comment: @VaughnOhlman: You can ask for the "first" example of such a work.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Ugh. That's even worse.

Comment: @Valorum 
I know, but it is within the rules, and given we've basically been accusing him of looking for a list, I figured it was only right to throw him a bone to a valid question.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is still a variant on the '[open-ended list question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic)' that the site frowns upon. You're basically inviting people to post examples of a trope.

> Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> **Questions calling for a list of works**, authors, …: **What are all the books that have X?** Who wrote about topic Y?

Trying to turn it into a mock yes/no question by replacing *"**What are all the** books that have X?"* with *"**Are there any** books that have X?"* doesn't stop it being a list question, it just means that you're sneaky.

Comment: It's interesting that the focus is on my motivation. Obviously if the site doesn't like the question, it doesn't like the question. But as for my motivation: I really don't want a list, not even one sneakily arrived at.

I like writing sci-fi; so in this case it would be more, "Wow, I would like to write a book where a future Earth uses the Gold standard. Oh, wait a minute, maybe its been done..."