# Let's pick some nice SFF questions to promote on other sites

Tags: discussion, advertising

With the [new Community Ads system](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13395/31394) for 2021, we now have the ability to choose **specific questions on SFF.SE** (no need to make custom images for them) and get them promoted in the sidebar or topbar of other SE sites. Obviously this is a nice opportunity to get some of our best content out there for more eyeballs, but we need to get a good list of stuff to promote. This is hard to coordinate via the above-linked meta posts, since answers there are required to be in a specific format with one proposal per answer, and it was getting messy to discuss via chat. So here's a new meta post specifically to **gather nice SFF questions to promote on other sites.**

---

Near neighbour sites with scope overlap (here we should try to choose SFF questions to promote so that they can't say "eh, that question could be asked on our site, why point to another site for it?"):

- Movies & TV
- Literature
- Arqade/Gaming
- Anime & Manga
- Role-Playing Games

Other sites that might be interested in specific parts of our content:

- Artificial Intelligence
- Robotics
- Space Exploration
- Arts & Crafts
- Worldbuilding
- Astronomy

Probably many others, these are just a few examples to bear in mind.

---

I'm making this post community wiki, so that it can have just one answer which can also be community wiki, and everyone can edit freely. Let's divide the answer into sections by site, and then in each section we can list/edit/add/remove some questions until we find a nice candidate to promote on one specific SE site.

Answer (score 8):

### Artificial Intelligence

Suggestions include:

- [What was the earliest appearance in SF of a likeable AI character?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216910/31394)
- [What is the earliest sci-fi story about humour and AI?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/236520/31394)
- [Which Sci-Fi work first showed hostile Artificial Intelligence?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/169699/31394)

### Chess

Suggestions include:

- [Why does the Party allow playing chess in Orwell's 1984?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189799/why-does-the-party-allow-playing-chess-in-orwells-1984)
- [How did Kirk regularly beat Spock in 4-Dimensional chess?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/239682/31394)

### Puzzling

Suggestions include:

- [Who wrote Tolkien's riddles?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81152/who-wrote-tolkiens-riddles)
- [What series of hard SF novels is this riddle describing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189246/31394)

Posted suggestions:

- [What was the earliest example of a riddle or puzzle being used as a security system?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13431/58193)

### Movies & TV

Suggestions include:

### Literature

Suggestions include:

### Arqade/Gaming

Suggestions include:

- [What Happened to the Dwemer?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97572/what-happened-to-the-dwemer)
- [Why do thieves wear unique and highly recognizable Thieves Guild armor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54795/why-do-thieves-wear-unique-and-highly-recognizable-thieves-guild-armor)
- [Is magic leaving Tamriel?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161820/is-magic-leaving-tamriel)
- [Why is the culture in Fallout stuck in the 1950s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32284/why-is-the-culture-in-fallout-stuck-in-the-1950s)
- [Are Deathclaws based on the Rancor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153206/are-deathclaws-based-on-the-rancor)
- [Were the Assassins from the Assassin's Creed series actual historical figures?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35891/were-the-assassins-from-the-assassins-creed-series-actual-historical-figures)
- [How exactly does the Animus work?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58964/how-exactly-does-the-animus-work)
- [If Haytham was a Templar, then why does he have the marking of the Creed on his hand armor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39494/if-haytham-was-a-templar-then-why-the-marking-of-the-creed-on-his-hand-armor)
- [How could the Lutece's plan ever possibly succeed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/47259/how-could-the-luteces-plan-ever-possibly-succeed)
- [What did Geralt of Rivia ask for his third wish?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106696/what-did-geralt-of-rivia-ask-for-his-third-wish)
- [What is the "Valley of Plenty" referenced in "Toss a Coin to Your Witcher"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/226138/what-is-the-valley-of-plenty-referenced-in-toss-a-coin-to-your-witcher)
- [What's wrong with this cat from Witcher 3: Wild Hunt?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153081/whats-wrong-with-this-cat-from-witcher-3-wild-hunt)
- [Why can't player characters in Resident Evil become infected with the T-Virus?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120315/why-cant-player-characters-in-resident-evil-become-infected-with-the-t-virus)
- [What happened to all the other Alice clones?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50407/what-happened-to-all-the-other-alice-clones)

### Anime & Manga

Suggestions include:

### Role-Playing Games

Suggestions include:

### Robotics

Suggestions include:

- [What was Asimov's contribution to real-world robotics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/587/what-was-asimovs-contribution-to-real-world-robotics)
- [How does Starfleet describe its laws of robotics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39102/how-does-starfleet-describe-its-laws-of-robotics)

### Space Exploration

Suggestions include:

- [First story to describe humans colonizing another planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181761/first-story-to-describe-humans-colonizing-another-planet)
- [What was the first work set in space that featured multiple civilizations but no aliens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122819/what-was-the-first-work-set-in-space-that-featured-multiple-civilizations-but-no)
- [First story that takes place outside the Milky Way](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37251/first-story-that-takes-place-outside-the-milky-way)

Posted suggestions:

- [What was the first Sci-Fi work to feature a spaceship?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13424/58193)

### Arts & Crafts

Suggestions include:

### Worldbuilding

Suggestions include:

- [What is the shape of the world of Westeros and do the Westerosi know?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22702/what-is-the-shape-of-the-world-of-westeros-and-do-the-westerosi-know)
- [What is the geometry of the universe in "The Wall of Darkness" by Arthur C Clarke?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63411/what-is-the-geometry-of-the-universe-in-the-wall-of-darkness-by-arthur-c-clark)

Posted suggestions:

- [How would one navigate on Larry Niven's "Ringworld"?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13423/58193)

### Astronomy

Suggestions include:

- [What was the first SciFi work that referred to Pluto as NOT a planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43775/what-was-the-first-scifi-work-that-referred-to-pluto-as-not-a-planet)
- [Earliest example of double planets in science fiction?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215475/earliest-example-of-double-planets-in-science-fiction)
- [Earth: Green Planet or Blue Planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100086/earth-green-planet-or-blue-planet)

---

### SFF

Meta suggestions include:

- [Should questions about future works be closed as Primarily Opinion Based?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5187/should-questions-about-future-works-be-closed-as-primarily-opinion-based)
- [Are *all* list questions off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/are-all-list-questions-off-topic)
- [What is our actual policy on science questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7364/what-is-our-actual-policy-on-science-questions)
- [What is the policy for spoilers?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers)
- [Where can I ask questions that aren't Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange questions?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/452/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-science-fiction-fantasy-stack-exchange-q)
- [How about revisiting our policy about "is there any" questions being OK?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12998/how-about-revisiting-our-policy-about-is-there-any-questions-being-ok)

Unanswered popular questions suggestions include:

- [Looking for science fiction assassination story with mysterious girl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27694/looking-for-science-fiction-assassination-story-with-mysterious-girl)
- [Spambot becomes self aware but every attempt to contact gets filtered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/192165/spambot-becomes-self-aware-but-every-attempt-to-contact-gets-filtered)
- [Story about enemies in a space battle sharing their last moments over com as their ships die](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37365/story-about-enemies-in-a-space-battle-sharing-their-last-moments-over-com-as-the)

Posted suggestions:

- [Married couple pretend to like each other due to crystal sculpture](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13433/58193)

Comment: I still want to know the answer to that crystal question...

Comment: Hey, what about the time travelling robots?