# Tags for Lego Star Wars

Tags: status-completed, tags, discussion

Do we need a tag for the Lego Star Wars franchise?  We have about five to ten questions about it, including

- [What is the canonicity of the new "Lego Star Wars: Droid Tales" TV show?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117442/4918)
- [What is the canonicity of Lego Star Wars (TV Episodes)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/56252/4918)
- [The red cup(?) in the Millennium Falcon (Lego 7965)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/8327/4918)
- [How many times is Jar Jar killed in Lego Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/117475/4918)
- [What is this Star Wars LEGO figure?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115231/4918)
- [What are these Star Wars Lego figures supposed to be?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115225/4918)
- [Does Lego Star Wars: The Freemaker Adventures contain spoilers for The Force Awakens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/133155/4918)

Questions that may or may not count, I don't know:

- [Did Darth Vader's TIE fighter appear in any version of Empire Strikes Back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/86006/4918)
- [Were the Death Star plans always in R2-D2?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/102610/4918)
- [Watchable star wars content besides the movies (and a few series)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111245/4918)

See also [questions tagged star-wars on 
LEGO® Answers (bricks) SE](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), currently 39 questions; and [questions tagged lego-star-wars or lego-star-wars-3 on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars+or+lego-star-wars-3), currently 24 questions.

Alternately, do we need a tag specifically for the TV series Lego Star Wars: The Freemaker Adventures which is debuting in 2016?

Comment: Could you edit this question to include a *full* list of all questions about Lego Star Wars? Then if the consensus is in favour of creating a tag for it, questions in the list can be crossed out one by one as they're slowly retagged.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: I can try.

Comment: tag everything. i eagerly await the tag for lego luke skywalker.

Comment: @b_jonas - There seems to be broad agreement from the community to the idea and no major dissenters. I suggest you start adding them 5 at a time over the next two days.

Comment: I've created a tag [Lego-Star-Wars] and appended it to a question.

Comment: @Valorum: only if you're certain that the remaining five questions linked don't need the tag.  (And [status-completed] is a moderator-only tag, but you probably know that.)

Comment: @b_jonas - Oops. Missed a few. Done now. And I'm pretty sure we don't need a tag for Freemaker.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Would you mind marking this one as completed?

Comment: @Valorum Sure. I haven't checked tags on all the questions, but I trust you :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:**

In light of the positive community response and lack of dissenting opinion to the answer below, I've appended the new [lego-star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars) tag to all of the site questions that are about Lego Star Wars.

### ----------

Yes, [Lego Star Wars](http://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars) is a **specifically different property** than [Star Wars](http://www.starwars.com/). As such, it should have its own tag which should be applied to questions which relate to the Lego Star Wars franchise, including Freemaker Adventures (which don't need their own tag).

If retagging needs to take place, it should be done in accordance with the [current policy on mass retagging](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/massive-retagging-editing) to avoid spamming the front page.

Comment: "different [...] **than**" - have you crossed the Atlantic?

Comment: @randal'thor - How very dare you, Sir. http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv243.shtml

Comment: [If you favour "different than", you’re highly likely to be a speaker of American English.](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/01/different-from-than-to/)

Comment: you  have both just shown that the british dont even know their own version of english. Himarmese will take over soon, just wait.

Comment: I just realised there's already a [tag:lego] tag. How about tagging all these questions [tag:lego] as well as [tag:star-wars], rather than creating a new [tag:lego-star-wars] tag?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I think Lego Star Wars is a sufficiently strong franchise on its own to merit a separate tag.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - There seems to be broad agreement with this idea from the community.