# Mass editing: Still a policy, or not?

Tags: discussion, editing

It was my understanding that, in general, there was [a community agreement](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1744/36526) not to edit too many older posts in a short period of time, to avoid cluttering the front page with too many older questions at once. However, particularly on Meta, but also on the main site, I've noticed an increased rate of bumped older questions recently.

**Is this the "new normal?" Should I just get used to seeing older questions bumped all the time?** Or do we need to have a conversation about this pattern of editing?

Comment: Oh, sorry I just bumped all those *The Twilight Zone* questions.

Comment: In [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe) sometimes TheLethalCarrot or Jenayah ping (Chat) users who edit more than five of the top fifteen active posts.

Comment: Define "mass". While I try to make sure to respect the 5/15 thing Rand and Storm mentioned, I've indeed been bumping old posts for a couple weeks now, mainly to create the work tags that go with them. Two or three in one go seemed reasonable, but if that bothers anyone, we can talk about it (here or in chat) and I'll hit the brakes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As of now, there has been no change in policy.**

Despite many discussions on meta, consensus has never swung dramatically against the policy not to flood the front page with edits. What exactly constitutes a "flood" of edits isn't always agreed upon by everyone, but there's a long-standing community policy (albeit not formally codified on meta) that **at most 5 of the top 15 posts on the front page should be last edited by the same person** (similar to [this meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3102/31394) where a mod proposed 4 of the top 10).

It's true that a few people recently are enjoying editing a lot of old posts, but they seem to be aware of the "5-in-15 rule" and *generally* not to be breaking it. Sometimes we (either mods, or other community members) observe someone going over the limit and ping them with a gentle reminder in chat or comments. If you see someone editing too much, you can ping them to let them know about the policy. (Anyone who's edited a post is @-pingable in comments on that post, so it's easy enough to ping a mass editor even if they don't use chat.)