# Are questions like this on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[How many of Philip José Farmers books were actually banned in the United States?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9490/how-many-of-philip-jose-farmers-books-were-actually-banned-in-the-united-states)

I see at least two problematic areas (neither are 100% clearly off topic, but not sure):

- The question is not Sci Fi related. If the book WAS banned it was for erotic/violent content, not the SciFi one.
- It's not at all clear that it was "banned" at all, since you can't really "ban" a book in the USA (1st Amendment issue), and only exclude it from certain kinds of libraries that would also exclude any other violent/pornorgraphic/erotic works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first issue doesn't preclude the question from being on-topic, as PJF was predominantly an SF writer. [Questions about the societal context of SF](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/364#364) are a recognized part of the site.

The second issue is perhaps a false premise in the question. This doesn't invalidate the question: post an answer and explain how the premise was flawed.

Comment: #1 Makes sense... I agree it's not off topic, though i WILL downvote unless he fixes his "banned" definition.

Comment: #2 - your judgement of the question makes sense. BUT... how is what you suggested I do NOT against the rules? It'd be a comment, not an answer?!

Comment: @DVK No, if the question is “why did you stop beating your wife”, then saying that you haven't been beating your wife, and preferably explaining what mistake lead the asker to come to this conclusion, is a valid answer.

Comment: :)))))))))))))))))))