# When and why did the flag reason change?

Tags: support, closing-questions, flagging

I was going to flag a question and noticed that the flagging reasons have changed radically since yesterday.

Was this discussed at some point because I can't find anything in meta about it.

Comment: Not to be a smartass, but if it's radically different from yesterday, I think it's pretty safe to say that it changed last night/this morning.

Comment: Well yes, obviously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It changed last night. I'm not going to go in to all of the details, but take a look at the blog post, http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/the-war-of-the-closes/

Comment: Why do I suddenly have images of a Vogon pointing out that the plans were on public display over in the next star system? Not everyone reads the blog, so wouldn't an announcement have been better?

Comment: @HorusKol: How are they going to do an announcement, and for what changes? SE is a fluid system, things change fairly frequently. If something seems odd, either ask in Meta or take a look at the blog, but I don't think they can cover everything. Also, keep an eye on MSO, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: The same way they announce elections? Ok, small tweaks here and there are one thing - but the changes to the close system were broad and sweeping. At the very least, they could have put a link to the blog post on the close options window so people would easily find out why these changes came about.

Answer (score 1):

While the topic did not read like an announcement, the changes were mentioned in [What should be our Off-Topic reasons?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2978/what-should-be-our-off-topic-reasons).