# Can a question about SF&F writers be in-scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I’ve got a question I’d like to ask about the activity of a group of SF writers (Asimov & Heinlein prominent among them) during WWII.

It seems to me that this community is where I’m most likely to find someone who knows the answer, but the question isn’t directly about SF itself. So, is such a question in-scope?

Edit: I’ve asked the question here: [Classified project during WWII involving Asimov and Heinlein](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/18776/1430)

Comment: Hmmm, it’s a meta-SF question; can I ask it here? ☺

Comment: I would say ask it at Literature.SE, but then I remembered that they closed :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, such a question would generally be in scope. It is a [“contextual question”](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/364#364) in the [list of common question topics](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic).