# What type of "behind the scenes" questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

The question regarding [how they created the hole in Robert Downey Jr's chest](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11403/how-did-they-create-the-hole-in-robert-downey-jr-s-chest-for-the-iron-man-movie#35573) was recently migrated to the Movies stack exchange. I agree that it is probably a better fit there, but as of last night, I saw that it had received 4 close votes for being "off-topic".

As Xantec pointed out the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq) notes that questions regarding

> Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

are on-topic.

Clara Onager mentioned that it was off-topic because

> This should be a movies and tv question as it primarily relates to a special effect technique and **only secondarily to scifi.**

But the same could be argued about a lot of [behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes) questions.

Take these questions, for example:

- [How did Weird Al Predict "The Phantom Menace"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11689/how-did-weird-al-predict-the-phantom-menace) This question is really about how Weird Al may have come across massive spoilers or leaked information (in truth, he didn't - it was all based on rumors).
- [Why are the Bene Gesserit tonsured/bald in the movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28267/why-are-the-bene-gesserit-tonsured-bald-in-the-movie) This question is really about why a director made a choice.
- [Why is Snarl not in Transformers: The Movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12468/why-was-snarl-not-in-the-transformers-the-movie) This question is really about why writers left someone out of the script.
- [What is the reason John Williams did not compose more for the Harry Potter Movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28710/what-is-the-reason-john-williams-did-not-compose-more-for-the-harry-potter-movie) This isn't a question about sci-fi/fantasy at all; It's about why a composer did not get/take a job.
- [How was E.T character created in the movie E.T -The Extra Terrestrial?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13127/how-was-e-t-character-created-in-the-movie-e-t-the-extra-terrestrial) Awfully similar to the Iron Man question - asking about how effects were created FOR a sci-fi/fantasy movie.
- [Why did Peter Allan Fields leave “Deep Space Nine”?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28154/why-did-peter-allan-fields-leave-deep-space-nine) This is about why a producer left a show.
- [How were the DRDs on Moya operated?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33770/how-were-the-drds-on-moya-operated) This is about how special effects units were operated.

I don't actually think that any of the above questions are off-topic. They may skirt that same line that the Iron Man question did, but they all fall into "behind the scenes and fandom information" regarding a sci-fi/fantasy work.

So, what sort of guidelines should we adhere to for defining what is, or is not "on-topic" in regards to "behind the scenes" questions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that question is squarely on topic for us here at Scifi.se.

I am not certain why it was migrated; if the OP was consulted, and agreed to the migration, then I see no problem with it being migrated.  It is equally on topic on both sites, imo.

However, if the question was migrated due to the close votes, I disagree with the migration (given that the OP does not appear to have a movies.se account, this seems more likely), and the closure.

With all due respect to Clara Onager, her comment appears to be strictly based upon opinion, without having [participated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8416/clara-onager) in any of the relevant meta discussions.  Her comment is contradicted by many examples, including the ones you cited.

I believe our [previous meta discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/356/1359) on "behind the scenes questions" is quite clear that these are perfectly acceptable here.

The question should not have been migrated unless the OP specifically requested it.

Comment: There was [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/619/should-questions-about-special-effects-techniques-be-allowed-on-science-fiction) more recent discussion on special effects questions.

Comment: @Keen Thanks for linking that.  I missed that discussion. Given the lack of consensus there, I think the current FAQ position still stands.