# Are questions about sci-fi/fantasy shows viewership on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I recently came across this question - [How is the audience of the Arrowverse spread amongst the 4 shows?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175503/how-does-the-audience-of-the-arrowverse-spread-amongst-the-4-shows)

The crux of the question is this:

> Maybe it is the mathematician in me speaking, but I always wondered how the viewership spread amongst the 4 shows. Which part of the audience watches all of them? Only one of them?
>
> Do we have any figure (from the CW or independent source) about the viewership of the Arrowverse?

Since this doesn't pertain to the SFF aspects of said shows, but audience totals, **is this on-topic or should it be closed?** I tend to think it might be better for [Movies&TV.SE](//movies.stackexchange.com), since they have some questions about such topics.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like trivia, but that's not off-topic anymore either.

Comment: So no SFF-Nal questions are always off-topic? Guess it’s time to close half the site...

Comment: That should say non-SFF-nal

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## [Behind-the-scenes questions are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/356/21267)

**This includes fandom information**. There's no need to move these types of questions to M&TV as they're perfectly valid, on-topic and [have precedence](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2944/21267).

In fact, our Help Center has the following guidance in [Help Center > Asking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted
>   towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes
>   questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - **Behind-the-scenes and fandom information**
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order
>
> <sub>[emphasised relevant part]</sub>

---

<sup>**Note:** partly adapted from [Why is fandom information treated as if it weren't on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9529/21267)</sup>

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like trivia, but that's not off-topic anymore either.

Comment: You can say that again!