# Can I ask a question about Star Wars/Star Trek fanfiction?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask whether it's okay to post a question asking about classic fanfiction of Star Trek/Star Wars written at the time the movies or original show came out, and specifically about the then unknown future. I have a feeling it might be going against some rule. Thanks
EDITED TO ADD: I mean to say, in the question I would be asking if people have any links to the above mentioned fanfiction.

Comment: There's 2 different questions. One is what the fanfic was called, another where to find it. If you know the name, AND googled and can't find it, and supply your google attempts in the question, should be fine. If you don't know the name, ask the story-ID question without the "where to read" part first.

Comment: I think I will leave it for now, as it doesn't relate to specific stories, just stories in general. I once read a Star Wars fan story called The Jedi Question that was written after Empire and before Jedi were released, and that's the kinda story I'd be searching for. Or Star Trek stories set in the 24th century but written at a point before TNG had been created, if this makes sense. Thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: that would be more of a request for story recommendation, which is considered off-topic here (since there's no possible "correct" aswer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [Meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/363/4516) *seems* to imply a consensus that requests to find a particularly hard-to-find piece of fiction are allowed, though it's a bit vague.

Comment: `These questions are about what a librarian or bookseller would typically know.` - I don't think it's referring to fanfiction, which AFAIK has been rather vague in general.

Comment: @Izkata One of the questions listed there is "Place to read moderated amateur work?", which seems to recognize fan-fiction as part of the bibliographic universe we accept.

Comment: Although, now that I check, it seems that that question *has* been moderated and removed, though perhaps because it was asking for an archive or list, not for a specific work.