# Can I ask if a book/movie/TV show is speculative fiction?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a few questions about where the line between non-genre and speculative fiction lies.

Speculative fiction being the collective term for Sci-fi, horror, fantasy and a few other closely related things - all of which should be ontopic for this site (as I understand things.)

To clarify my undertanding of what is and is not speculative fiction, I would like to ask 2 or 3 questions. Along the lines of:

- is John Marsden's Tomorrow speculative fiction?
- is the BBC Sherlock or CBS Elementary speculative fiction

*Please **don't** answer them here (or in comments). I want to know if I can ask them (or questions like them) on the main site.*

Would such questions be on topic?

Comment: Would such questions be on topic _here_, on meta?

Comment: @sqb - You'd probably get away with it in meta, but those sorts of questions would be much better suited to chat

Comment: We had questions like this in Meta before and handled them quite well.

Answer (score 7):

From the [Help Page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
[image: off topic pic]

No, is X science fiction (etc) is off topic.
Read the Manual.

See also [discussion here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/362#362).

Comment: after getting @PearsonArtPhoto's answer I decided to poke around to find the reference.  I was going to post this as an edit to their answer, but you can't do that in meta. So I guess I will answer myself

Comment: I meant to post the reference, but it was too hard to do from my phone... Glad to know it was given.

Answer (score 1):

No. "Is this science fiction" questions are off topic.