# Is question 39423 (origin of "reaping" souls) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions

I just got a vote to close as off-topic on [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/what-is-the-origin-of-the-concept-of-reaping-souls) with the following comment:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a fantasy or sci-fi character or plot device. —[Andres F.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/770/andres-f) ([*source*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39423/what-is-the-origin-of-the-concept-of-reaping-souls#comment184883_39423))

The question asks about the origin of a particular concept which is fantastical in nature and widely used in sci-fi and fantasy, but is not specific to a particular work or series of works.

Are such questions on- or off-topic? The help center pages don't clearly indicate whether this is on- or off-topic, and it did seem on-topic to me. Specificially, I would want to argue that it falls under [this topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/364#364), but I can't say for sure.

Comment: Related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5014/can-i-ask-about-mythology. Although that discussion suggests that your question is off-topic, we haven't always been consistent on this front

Comment: What would explain the +7 score then?

Comment: For the record it does look pretty darned off-topic. If this question wasn't the subject of a meta question, I'd probably mod-close it right now.

Comment: @DragonLord - Because people sometimes upvote things that aren't on topic if they find them interesting.

Comment: @Richard: Go ahead and close. It lacks specificity to any modern sci-fi/fantasy work.

Comment: @DragonLord - I shall leave it to the community to make a judgement.

Comment: are any/all of the upvotes recent? the community has been known to change its mind and stance on things over time.

Comment: The upvotes weren't recent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is absolutely on topic for this site. We have a canonical meta question where the various kinds of questions were judged, by the community, as on-topic or off-topic, and yours falls squarely into the "[Contextual Questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/364#364)" category

In particular, that category of on-topic questions includes:

> These types of questions deal with the context in which science fiction and fantasy occurs: including history, etymology, and society. They have definitive answers about specific facts or events related to science fiction and fantasy.

It even gives an example of such an op-topic question:

> [What is the origin of the phrase "on the gripping hand?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/392/what-is-the-origin-of-the-phrase-on-the-gripping-hand)

*Most* of our questions here are related to a known work of fiction, but that doesn't mean they all have to be. Your question is about *some* work of science fiction or fantasy, you just don't know what it is yet; it has a correct answer, and someone who is knowledgable about science fiction could be expected to answer it.

Comment: I think there is a fine line between contextual/on-topic and contextual/off-topic, but IMO, if the question lies mostly in the side of "what an anthropologist/historian would study", then it's offtopic. Cultural and historical depictions of Death are mostly outside the scope of this site. It's folklore and early religion -- if we allow this, then we allow stories of the Bible, which in turn have the potential to offend some people if we consider them *fiction*.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see a difference between your question and any of our "[What was the first X](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%22what+is+the+first%22)" questions, of which we have at least twenty and not a single one is closed. I think this is just an instance of the community being fickle, but there's not a whole lot we can do about that.

Comment: I dislike most of those questions (note: *dislike*, not sure whether they're on-topic, but regardless I find them useless. I *wish* they were off-topic). This question about Death, on the other hand, I find interesting but off-topic. It's not about a specific appearance in a work of fantasy or sci-fi, but about a folklore/historical depiction, how could it possibly be on-topic?

Comment: @AndresF. I don't particularly like this type of question either, but the community has quite clearly decided they're on-topic. Most of the questions in the search I posted are not asking about a particular work, that's the whole point of the question "what was the first work". And many of them do go back to folklore; what is folklore anyway, if not fantasy?