# Are questions about SF-related websites on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

We know that books,  short stories,  graphic novels,  TV shows,  movies, and **computer games** are on-topic.  What about websites?

Specifically, I was wondering about the history and etymology of chakoteya.net.   But this is just an example.  Of course,  I mean questions about a website itself,  not just about the same topic as the website, where the website figures into the question.

Comment: For the record, I have an answer to your question about where the name chakoteya came from if you want to ask the question...

Comment: @Richard, I do,  but I can't if it's going to be closed as off topic.  Got a suggestion?    I'm actually a little disturbed by the arbitrary cutoff.   What if I asked where transcripts can be found online? Wouldn't that be on topic?  Is the question on topic for meta?

Comment: Asking about the background of a scifi-fandom site is probably on topic. Asking for a list of sites is almost certainly off-topic.

Answer (score 7):

I think that if the question is about a topic where the answer is likely to come from SFF works' content (e.g. etymology of chakoteya.net) it's ontopic.

If it is totally unrelated to in-universe, it's probably offtopic (e.g. history of that website seems like offtopic to me)

Answer (score 4):

If you're asking about the *site* itself, not the site's *contents*, it's probably off-topic. From the close dialog:

> This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

And from that link, we see types of questions that are on-topic:

> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

The only thing here that this type of question could fall into is `behind-the-scenes and fandom information`, but this is more referring to questions surrounding the development of the particular story or world.

I don't know much about your particular example, but unless whatever world that particular site talks about is the main source for the lore of that world, it's probably off-topic. For a slightly more detailed explanation of what constitutes "behind-the-scenes", see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/356#356). Even so, such a question would need to be constrained so as to focus on the development of the lore.

**TL;DR:** If your question deals with solely a website, it's probably off-topic, unless that website was used as a vehicle for the development of the story.