# Why is fandom information treated as if it weren't on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

From the [Help Center > Asking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted
>   towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes
>   questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal    context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes **and fandom information**
> - Story    identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

It says it right there, people. Questions about behind-the-scenes **and fandom information** are indeed ON TOPIC. However, I have often seen these questions discriminated againt simply because some users don't care for them. For example:

Main example:

- [Into which house was Rowling sorted?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/126388/into-which-house-was-rowling-sorted) was closed, reopened, and closed again as off topic when it really is on topic, falling under fandom info.

Sub examples:

- [What has been Harrison Ford's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111992/what-has-been-harrison-fords-attitude-toward-star-wars), [What has been Alec Guinness's attitude toward Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111996/what-has-been-alec-guinnesss-attitude-toward-star-wars), and [Kenny Baker's attitude toward Star Wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112128/kenny-bakers-attitude-toward-star-wars) each had some backlash for some users who erroneously belived that fandom information wasn't on topic, when it really is on topic. See also [Laine Liska’s—and everybody and their cousins’—attitude toward Star Wars](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7799/laine-liska-s-and-everybody-and-their-cousins-attitude-toward-star-wars)
- [Did Harrison Ford ever tell fans he used to be himself, and why?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124078/did-harrison-ford-ever-tell-fans-he-used-to-be-himself-and-why) was said to be off topic in some of the comments, with some users sounding like they were threatening to VTC.
- <sub>https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124431/why-does-stan-lee-make-a-cameo-in-the-princess-diaries-2 isn't a very good example, but it *could* fall under fandom information (but I do realize it's not a *great* question).</sub>

It seems like some users treat fandom info questions as off topic. **Why is fandom information treated as if it weren't on topic?**

Comment: Basically, because people aren't familiar enough with site scope.

Comment: Because "fandom information" isn't defined anywhere, and means different things to different people.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Indeed, I wouldn't have recognized any of the OP's examples as "fandom information". I would have have thought "fandom information" was for questions about fan organizations and conventions, fan history, fanzines, fanspeak, and BNFs. The OP's examples look more like "movie trivia" or "celebrity trivia" to me.

Answer (score 17):

Historically, (and incorrectly) because a number of people believe that since the question does not have anything to do with a SF/F element of the work, it is off-topic.

However, every time the topic comes up on meta, fandom and behind-the-scenes information is deemed on-topic.

If you see a question closed for one of these reasons, either vote to re-open or flag it for mod action.

Related:

- [How should we handle questions that are about non-SF/F elements in a SF/F work?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6594/5184)
- [What type of “behind the scenes” questions are on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2944/5184)
- [Are questions about SF-related websites on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7503/5184)

Answer (score -2):

**I suggest we create a tag for fandom information.**

There is already a tag for [behind-the-scenes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behind-the-scenes) so it makes sense. That way, once there's a tag for [fandom-information](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fandom-information), any users who prefer not to see them can simply add [fandom-information](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fandom-information) to their [ignored tags list.](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1979/can-you-exclude-a-tag-from-showing-up)

Comment: I don't think that would be a useful tag...

Comment: @AncientSwordRage (1) how would it not be useful? I think it'd be very helpful. And (2) if it's not useful, then what do you propose?

Comment: This seems like a fine idea to me, but the main solution will be to make people aware of what is and is not on topic here.

Comment: @anaranjada: Considering it is already in the Asking help article, how else would you make people aware?

Comment: @Ellesedil perhaps this meta post will help. Either that, or we’re doomed to endless reopen wars.

Comment: @Ellesedil In my experience, tags can help convince people it's on topic. Some people might think toy story is off topic, but then they look and see there are tags for toy story 1 and 2! :)

Comment: the existence of tags means nothing. anyone with enough rep can create any tag.

Comment: What is your definition of "fandom information"? I would have thought "fandom information" is "information about fandom" but I guess you have something very different in mind.

Comment: @RedCaio - I don't think it would be helpful. Plus, the only motivation for creating such a tag seems to be to justify the fact that some people (mentioning no names) feel that it's off-topic and want to segregate it.

Comment: This would fall squarely under the definition of a "meta-tag", wouldn't it?