# Can I ask for movies/books related with a particular sci-fi movie?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Since I'm done with the series and books of a sci-fi movie and can't decide whether what story should I read next, can I ask some recommendations of movie or book related to sci-fi? If this is allowed, what **tag/tags** should I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO.**

Recommendation questions are strictly off-topic as defined by the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> What about other Science Fiction and Fantasy related questions?
>
> Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> - Questions calling for a list of works, authors, …: What are all the
>     books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?
> - **Reading or viewing recommendations: I liked X, what should I watch next?**
> - Genre classification: Is X Science Fiction?

Other Relevant meta:

[What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/365#365)

Comment: Okay. Is there a specific chat room that is active until now where I can ask for recommendations?

Comment: @BookStriker There used to be a chat reserved for recommendations. It went on auto-freeze due to inactivity. I would suggest just using the main chat room now. Chat actively has died out lately, so if your questions were to receive any attention it would be there.