# How/where to ask question that the FAQ says is off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd recently discovered Australian SF writer Greg Egan, and it occurred to me that SF.SE would be a good place to find the answer to a question inspired by his work - not specifically about his work, but finding works by other authors that have a specific similar characteristic. Based on [What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic/351#351), the question that I would ask is clearly off-topic - but it's not really a question that's amenable to typical web research methods. Thus, given the off-topic question below, I'd like to know either how I can render it on-topic, or where a good site to ask it would be.

> Author Greg Egan has written a number of stories where he makes a fundamental change to the nature of space (rather than just postulating that something we currently believe is impossible is in fact possible, like FTL, psi, etc., and seeing how human society would change). Examples of this are his Orthogonal series, where he postulates that there is no real distinction between 'space-like' and 'time-like' movement, and Dichronauts, where the distinction still exists, but he postulates two 'time-like' directions. He then follows the math through, and builds his worlds based on what the math says.
>
> What other authors have done similar worldbuilding, and in what books?

Comment: Reddit, probably. Or Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Or perhaps [chat], depending on who's around.

Comment: See the entry for '[Alternate Cosmos](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/alternate_cosmos)' in the *SF Encyclopedia*, which has examples of works in this sub-genre. Then, follow the "[Incoming/Citation](http://sf-encyclopedia.uk/incoming.php?&entry=alternate_cosmos)" link for more examples.

Answer (score 15):

On the network the best place would be in chat, specifically [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58631/the-restaurant-at-the-end-of-the-universe), SFF’s main chatroom. I imagine the chat over on Literature.SE might be able to help to but I’ve never been in to know who hangs around there.